# Opening and executing multiple concurrent Windows command prompts from Python

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to automate some tedious command-line use in Windows.

I need to open an instance of Zookeeper's server, then open a new command prompt and open an instance of Apache Kafka's server. I'd like to be able to open new command prompt windows and execute new commands on them.

What separates this from other queries I've found on StackOverflow is that I need all of these processes to be running concurrently. I need the Zookeeper and Kafka servers to both be active.

So, for example, this code fails.

```
os.system (ZOOKEEPER_START_SERVER + ' ' + ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG)
os.system (KAFKA_START_SERVER + ' ' + KAFKA_SERVER_CONFIG)
```

It starts the Zookeeper server, but because the server runs indefinitely in the background, the program hangs.

I need to somehow open the Kafka server in a new command prompt, and ideally continue running my Python script, opening new windows as necessary for accessing the contents of the Kafka server.

I'm able to do what I want by putting the above two lines in methods, manually opening the file in interactive mode, executing the relevant function, then repeating in a new command window.

This is far too tedious for my current purposes, but I hope it makes the issue clearer.

I hope I've been clear. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options.  You could try:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([ZOOKEEPER_START_SERVER, ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

Alternatively you could use the [start command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to allow the user to interact with the windows:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('cmd /C "start (' + ZOOKEEPER_START_SERVER + ' ' + ZOOKEEPER_CONFIG + ')"')
subprocess.call('cmd /C "start (' + KAFKA_START_SERVER + ' ' + KAFKA_SERVER_CONFIG + ')"')
```

If you're looking to programmatically interact with the windows, you'll need to use `subprocess.Popen` with pipes, which you can read about in the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).